# Difference between ASIHttpRequest S3 and AWS SDK for iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, asihttprequest

For iOS developers, we have two options to user Amazon S3 service with

[ASIHttpRequest S3](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3)

[AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/)

Seem like they are doing the same thing to provide interface to use S3 service.

My question is what is the difference between them if have ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

AWS SDK supports more options for IAM (Identity and Access Management), policies and STS (temporary or "federated" users).  Additionally, it provides support for services other than S3.

If you just need to move data to/from S3 I believe ASI is the way to go.  If you're doing anything that uses other AWS services, or requires anything beyond standard ID/SECRET authentication, the SDK is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ASI in a large application for access to S3 and SimpleDB and a few other things. I found that there are a few bugs, etc. Performance is good, though. So I am trying the AWS-sdk for next project. I think in the long run that the official SDK will be better, as Amazon appears to spend money on supporting (and writing?) it.